# Unable to connect to SQL Server remotely

Tags: sql-server, wpf, sql-server-2008, deployment, connection-string

I have a fully funtional WPF application running on my local machine with SQL Server 2008 as database. SQL Server Management studio is also setup on my machine. Now I want my application to be accessible over the company network so that other users can use my app. I have created install shield any installed the application on another windows 7 machine but on launching the app when database call is made using `EntityFramework 6.0`  i get these error messages `(exceptions/inner exceptions)`.

```
The Underlying Provider failed on Open
```

[image]

```
The system can not find the file specified
```

I have enabled TCP/IP in SQL Server configuration manager and the port is set to 1433. SQL Server named instance and this is how configuration manager looks like

[image]

Firewall on machine (on which SQL server is installed/hosted) is TURNED OFF. Here is my connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="TestPacksContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TestPacksModel.csdl|res://*/TestPacksModel.ssdl|res://*/TestPacksModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=IMCCIT101\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=TPM;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

So I believe I have all the settings enabled that I should have but still I am not able to connect to the SQL server.

**P.S: I have not installed Sql server or SQL Server Management studio or anything special on the client machine**

Comment: did you check after restarting the instance ?

Comment: please start `SQL Server Agent(SQLEXPRESS)` service which is stopped we can see in your posted image

Comment: @tinka SQL server agent is not available in SQLEXPRESS! And is also not needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

As it turned out after chat, the problem was something very different.
The domainmodel is located in a seperate assembly and the connection string config was only located in the app.config of this class library. But an `AppDomain` can only have a single config file, see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/).

So to fix, add:

```
<connectionStrings> 
 <add name="TestPacksContext" 
    connectionString=
         "metadata=res://*/TestPacksModel.csdl|res://*/TestPacksModel.ssdl|res://*/TestPacksModel.msl; 
          provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;
          data source=IMCCIT101\SQLEXPRESS,1433;
          initial catalog=TPM;integrated security=True;
          MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
          providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> 
 </connectionStrings>
```

to the `app.config` of the main application.

You have 2 problems in your connectionstring.

1. You need to specify the port in your connectionstring. As described [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Change:

```
data source=IMCCIT101\SQLEXPRESS;
```

to:

```
data source=IMCCIT101\SQLEXPRESS,1433;
```

You also need to make sure port 1433 is opened by windows firewall. You can use a simple tool like `Telnet` to test if you can connect to port 1433 on IMCCIT101.

Also make sure the clients have working DNS, so can find the IP address of IMCCIT101.

2. You specify two different authentication methods!

You say:

```
integrated security=True;
```

but also specify the credentials for the sa user (see below for other reasons why you should not do this).

I assume you're hosting the DB on your laptop and you therefore can't, or at least not easily, use windows integrated security. So change `integrated security' to:

```
 integrated security=False;
```

**Security Notice:**

You provide the user on the other machines with the `sa` credentials of your SQL server. Are you aware anybody with this credentials is able to do virtually anything with your SQL server, including deleting databases, etc.

Windows integrated security is the preferred way of connecting to a database. If that is not an option create sql users for your users!

You'll still not completely there as their password will be stored in plain text on their machines.

In other words, if you can, host your SQL server database on central server in an Active Directory environment, so you can use integrated security.

Comment: I set User ID and Passowrd purely for testing purposes. I am not using it anymore (I have edited the question as well). I have added port 1433 to the connection string, used telnet command on client machine to see port is open or not it turned out to be open. but still I am not able to connect. Same issue :s btw how do I make sure client machine has working DNS and can find IP Address of IMCCIT101?

Comment: I have not installed Sql server or anything sql software of client machine, could that be a problem?

Comment: No it is not necessary to install sql tools or whatever on the client machine.

Comment: If you use integrated security are you running in an AD environment and do the AD users have permissions on your SQL server?

Comment: How do I check this AD thing?

Comment: I think you don't understand what integrated security means. Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266913(v=vs.60).aspx). It basically means you're computer and the clienst computers are connected to a windows network where usermanagement is done centrally using a windows server domain controller.

Comment: yes I am on a domain network and all users are being authenticated by AD. I have added new Login credentials in SQL Server Management studio for users on whose machine I am installing the application and given the rights to the particular database as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89909/discussion-between-ric-net-and-wasim-qadir).

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and support Indeed you're a GEEK :)